# How to to check Excel sheet column-name row using ExcelDataReader?

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

Assume I have an Excel work sheet with first row that must be column names:

```
FirstName  LastName   DepartmentId     <-- first row is column names
john       doe         1
jane       doe         2
...
```

I have 2 questions:
- How can I check if the first row is column names by requirement of the work sheet?
- If the first row is column names, how can I check those column names match predefined names such as FirstName, LastName, and DepartmentId?

Comment: the exceldatareader should have a IsFirstRowAsColumnNames  property that is a boolean value.

Comment: This is to late to comment here! But which language are you using C#, Java, VB.Net , ... ?